# several tomcat apps running as user, using single java jdk installation owned by root

Tags: security, java, file-permissions

We administer server with java web applications: alfresco/solr running on tomcat.

Up to now java jdk sources of same versions were extracted/copied in several directories next to each other, so duplicated. They were owned by the respectiv user, a user for alfresco, another one for solr and a few more.

I try to deduplicate that and now i have

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   22 Jan 23 10:24 java_alf -> /srv/java/jdk-11.0.13/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jan 23 08:20 java_solr -> /srv/java/jdk-11.0.13
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Jan 23 09:03 jdk-11.0.13
```

Same with tomcat, two identical copies before, and now just symlinks.

The websites of alfresco are working.

My question is about security - might a process gain root priviliges and do some harm?

ps aux : (zrz-alf... is the local service user)

```
zrz-alf+ 21142  1.2 25.3 4790128 1017248 ?     Sl   09:10   1:00 /srv/java/java_alf/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=....
```

So IMO this is okay. Is this true? Or do we need a linux group where user root and the app-user is member? Or is there some other way to accomplish this?
I am also interested in general explanations and some resources where this is explained

We use SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP5

Comment: As long as no security flaw is found in the installed JRE a regular user can't gain root privileges just by using said JRE. It's the default configuration when you install a JRE via the system package manager. There is nothing special to set up for it.

Comment: thank you for the confirmation; Glad to hear I was not completely on the wrong track.